# How to precache user-specific content with Workbox?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, sw-precache, workbox

I have a membership site and I want to create cache files for only logged-in users. How is it possible to do with [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) ?

**Solution:** I found that workbox has a very good feature in this case. It is possible to use [cacheable response](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-cacheable-response). So from the server I could send specific header values like this:

```
response.setHeader('X-Is-Cacheable', 'true')
```

And in my service-worker I could check whether that header value is matched or not like this:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/path/to/api/'),
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'api-cache',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
        headers: {
          'X-Is-Cacheable': 'true',
        },
      })
    ]
  })
);
```

So if the X-Is-Cacheable is set to true by the server(I set it `true` only for logged-in users) then all the data would be cached for that user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write your own handler that checks if the user is logged in then caches the response

see: [Handling a Route with a Custom Callback](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests)

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use Stale While Revalidate strategy for logged in users and Network Only for users who are not logged in? I mean is it possible to use workbox strategis for different conditions of one route?